# PHP file upload and rename to specific name to overwrite previous version

Tags: php, file, upload, rename, overwrite

I'm trying to make it easy to update menus(two PDFs) online for some coworkers by creating a small upload form to upload the PDF into the menus directory and give it a specific name so that it overwrites the previous version.

Here is what I have so far...

Form:

```
<section>
<form action="menu_uploader.php" method="post" id="menu_upload" name="menu_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<p><label for="wine_list_menu_upload">Wine List -> </label>&nbsp;<input type="file" name="wine_list_menu_upload" id="wine_list_menu_upload"></p>
<p><label for="food_flight_menu_upload">Food &amp; Flights -> </label>&nbsp;<input type="file" name="food_flight_menu_upload" id="food_flight_menu_upload"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit"></p>
</form>
</section>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if( ($_FILES["wine_list_menu_upload"]["type"] == "application/pdf") &&
    ($_FILES["food_flight_menu_upload"]["type"] == "application/pdf") &&
    ($_FILES["wine_list_menu_upload"]["size"] < 1048576*5) && 
    ($_FILES["food_flight_menu_upload"]["size"] < 1048576*5))
    {   
        if($_FILES["wine_list_menu_upload"]["error"] > 0 || $_FILES["food_flight_menu_upload"]["error"] > 0)    
            {echo "Error Code: " . $_FILES["wine_list_menu_upload"]["error"] xor $_FILES["food_flight_menu_upload"]["error"] . "<br>";}
                else
                    {move_uploaded_file($_FILES["wine_list_menu_upload"]["tmp_name"], "tasting-bar/menus/test/SEWC-Wine_Menu.pdf");
                     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["food_flight_menu_upload"]["tmp_name"], "tasting-bar/menus/test/SEWC-Food_Flight_Menu.pdf");
                        echo "Menus uploaded successfully!"; }
    }

else
  {
  echo "Invalid file type. Must be a PDF and under 5MB. Sorry!<br/>";
  echo "File Type - " . $_FILES["wine_list_menu_upload"]["type"] . "<br/>";
  echo "File Name - " . $_FILES["wine_list_menu_upload"]["name"];

  }

?>
```

I need to get "wine_list_menu_upload" renamed to "SEWC-Wine_Menu.pdf" and into "tasting-bar/menus/" and
"food_flight_menu_upload" renamed to "SEWC-Food_Flight_Menu.pdf" and into "tasting-bar/menus/"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you set write permission for the folder ?

Comment: Have you tried using a full folder description, `C:\tasting-bar\menus\`?

Comment: The directory "tasting-bar/menus/" is set at 777

Comment: This webserver is on GoDaddy. Not sure what the rest would look like. http://sewinecollective.com/tasting-bar/menus ?

Comment: is it windows or linux server ?

Comment: Linux. Figured it out but I can't answer my own question cause I'm a newbie around here. I inserted this at the top of the script... $dir_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; Then put $dir_root just before the desired path. Thanks for your inputs! All is good now

Comment: i think you can answer but cant vote up

Comment: It said I had to wait 8 hours :( @AkhilSidharth

Answer (score 0):

try adding these lines just before `move_uploaded_file`

```
chmod('tasting-bar/', 0777);
chmod('tasting-bar/menus', 0777);
chmod('tasting-bar/menus/test/', 0777);
```

if its permission issue, it should solve with this

Comment: Figured it out but I can't answer my own question cause I'm a newbie around here. I inserted this at the top of the script... $dir_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; Then put $dir_root just before the desired path. Thanks for your input!